# How can I convert a swing JTextField component in to an object of a type that extends it

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, jtextfield, mouse-listeners

I have an application using a third party package that has a factory that returns to me JTextField objects that are then added to a GUI. This makes up about 10% of the JTextFields used.

I can't change the third party package but have a requirement to add right click (cut, copy and paste) options in to all ofthe fields.

Now I have a RightClickTextField that extends JTextField and has all the functionality built in to it, this serves to solve my issue for 90% of the application.

However for the 10% that's using the third party package to get JTextFields I cannot think of a solution that will allow me to declare the fields as RightClickTextFields yet use the factory I have to get back the Boxes. I know I cannot cast the result as the objects returned are not of a type that high up in the hierarchy, and a copy constructor won't work since I cannot copy every property being set by the factory, but I don't know of a way to upcast the JTextField in to my type. Is there one?

Comment: I am not sure I completely get your question, but couldn't you use composition, instead of inheritance? Instead of having RightClickTextField extending JTextfield, I would try to have RightClickTextField with a JTextField member.

Comment: Sounds like you do get it, I have thought about doing it that way but I don't really want to have composites, with all their various properties and settings, adding to my memory footprint. I want a way to convert the JTextField objects in to RightClickTextFields and am wondering if there's some clever trick that can be used to do that. If not I will probably just add a Util class that adds the right click stuff on to a JTextField. But I don't want to do it that way.

Comment: As @GuillaumePolet suggests, Swing uses [delegation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) like this in several places, e.g. `DefaultCellEditor`.

Comment: the problem is that the 90% did it the wrong way ;-)

Comment: I don't think delegation is the way forward, There's too many methods to delegate, and my delegating class would have to extend the text field to allow adding to the swing components, so I'd have 2 Text Field objects created for each field. My Plan is to create a Util class that will add listeners on to JText Fields, I would do this with a factory except I already have a factory handing me the fields that I cannot replace. Though I could delegate the call to that factory from my factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than subclassing or trying to cast it, can you put your right-click functionality into its own class which implements the [MouseInputListener interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/event/MouseInputListener.html), and simply add an instance of your right-click handler to the JTextField objects in question?

Comment: I know there are other solutions, but I want it done this way to maintain consistency throughout the codebase, If this isn't possible then I will have to re-think. But I want to know if anyone has any really bright ideas first.

Comment: I guess it's a question of whether or not you can change the app layout. If you can get a `JTextField` from the 3rd party package and create a constructor for `RightClickTextFields` that takes a `JTextField` (from the 3rd party package) and gives you back a `RightClickTextField`, then that'll work but you'll have to also replace the `JTextField` in the app layout with your new `RightClickTextField`. There's no way that I know of to just convert an object from one type to another via something like casting unless they share the proper class ancestry.

Comment: To say it another way, you can't cast an object of one type into its subtype unless it's actually an instance of that subtype. The only way around this that I know of is to create a factory or constructor that takes an instance of the parent type and uses that to create an instance of subtype, with the attributes copied over.

Comment: The constructor option was a consideration, but the problem is that there's a lot of stuff to copy, across to the new type. I am able to change the fields in the application to be RightClickTextField just not able to change the factory class that I'm using to get the JTextFields. I'll have to go with the Util Option I think.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use the [Decorator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). This way you can stop using `RightClickTextField` at all - start using `RightClickTextFieldDecorator` and supply it either with your own `JTextField`s or the ones you get from 3rd party thingy.

Comment: I don't think the decorator pattern would work in this situation. If I understand the pattern correctly, the Decorator would need to extend JTextField but override all of it's methods with stubs that called the equivalent method on the passed in object?

I think the best was is to pass the new JTextFields through a static method somewhere that adds the functionality to it. It's just that that method wouldn't be all that clean. My RightClickTextField implements the listeners required, and can therfore easily call the cut/copy/paste functions on itself. It's nice and clean.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the comments. I think the actual answer to my question is:

You can't.

Whilst all of the suggestions are valid, I knew it was possible to do all those things, I just wanted to know if I could do it my way first.

My solution (based on feedback here and my own preference) was to create this class below, and manage and expose a single instance of it from a singleton.

I'd appreciate thoughts on this solution?

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class CopyPasteTextComponentPopoupMenu extends JPopupMenu implements
    ActionListener {


private JTextComponent lastInvoker;
private JMenuItem cutMenuItem;
private JMenuItem copyMenuItem;
private JMenuItem pasteMenuItem;

private Map<JTextComponent, JTCProperties> managedComponents;

private MouseListener heyListen;

public CopyPasteTextComponentPopoupMenu() {
    super();
    init();
}

public CopyPasteTextComponentPopoupMenu(String label) {
    super(label);
    init();
}

@Override
public void show(Component invoker, int x, int y) {

    JTCProperties props = managedComponents.get(invoker);
    if(props!=null) {
        this.lastInvoker = (JTextComponent) invoker;
        setEnabled(props);
        super.show(invoker, x, y);
    } else {
        this.lastInvoker = null;
    }
}

public void manageTextComponent(JTextComponent jtc, boolean canCut,
        boolean canCopy, boolean canPaste) {

    jtc.addMouseListener(heyListen);

    JTCProperties props = new JTCProperties(canCut,canCopy,canPaste);
    managedComponents.put(jtc,props);

}

public void dispose() {
    for (JTextComponent component : managedComponents.keySet()) {
        component.removeMouseListener(heyListen);
        managedComponents.remove(component);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (lastInvoker != null) {
        if (e.getSource() == cutMenuItem) {
            lastInvoker.cut();
        } else if (e.getSource() == copyMenuItem) {
            lastInvoker.copy();
        } else if (e.getSource() == pasteMenuItem) {
            lastInvoker.paste();
        }
    }
}

private void setEnabled(JTCProperties props) {
    cutMenuItem.setEnabled(props.canCut);
    copyMenuItem.setEnabled(props.canCopy);
    pasteMenuItem.setEnabled(props.canPaste);
}

private void init() {
    this.managedComponents = new HashMap<JTextComponent, JTCProperties>();
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 70));
    cutMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Cut");
    copyMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Copy");
    pasteMenuItem = new JMenuItem("Paste");

    cutMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    copyMenuItem.addActionListener(this);
    pasteMenuItem.addActionListener(this);

    this.add(cutMenuItem);
    this.add(copyMenuItem);
    this.add(pasteMenuItem);

    heyListen = new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }

        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.isPopupTrigger()) {
                show(e.getComponent(), e.getX(), e.getY());
            }
        }
    };
}

private class JTCProperties {
    public boolean canCut, canCopy, canPaste;

    public JTCProperties(boolean canCut, boolean canCopy, boolean canPaste) {
        this.canCut = canCut;
        this.canCopy = canCopy;
        this.canPaste = canPaste;
    }
}
```

}